# Call FtpClient once to list directories recursively

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I have a recursive function:

```
class FtpFolder{
public void ListChildren(IFolder folder)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://127.0.0.1/");
    FtpClient ftpClient = new FtpClient();
    ftpClient.Host = uri.Host;
    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserLocal", "1234");
    ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory(folder.FullName);
    foreach (FtpListItem item in ftpClient.GetListing(ftpClient.GetWorkingDirectory(), FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size))
    {
        switch (item.Type)
        {
            case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory:
                FtpFolder ftpSubFolder = new FtpFolder(item);
                folder.Folders.Add(ftpSubFolder);
                ListChildren(ftpSubFolder);
                break;
            case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File:
                folder.Files.Add(new FtpFile() { Item = item });
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this my class connection

```
class Connection{
private uri Uri;
private string Username;
private string Password
public connection(uri _uri, string _username, _password){
_uri=Uri; _username=Username; _password=Password;
}
public void connect(){
}
}
```

I use this recursive function to list all files from an FTP server. My question is can I reuse a single instance of `FtpClient` so I don't need to keep recreating a new one?

Comment: I've reworded your question and I'm 99% sure this is what you meant, but please check this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void ListChildren(IFolder folder)
{
    FtpClient ftpClient = new FtpClient
    {
        Host = new Uri("ftp://127.0.0.1/").Host,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserLocal", "1234");
    };
    ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory(folder.FullName);

    ListChildren(ftpClient, ftpClient.GetWorkingDirectory());
}

private void ListChildren(FtpClient ftpClient, IFolder folder)
{
    foreach (FtpListItem item in folder, FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size))
    {
        switch (item.Type)
        {
            case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory:
                FtpFolder ftpSubFolder = new FtpFolder(item);
                folder.Folders.Add(ftpSubFolder);

                ListChildren(ftpSubFolder);
                break;
            case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File:
                folder.Files.Add(new FtpFile { Item = item });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i use that in other class, I mean I have other class name connection and the value of host, username and password I get from windows form and i put function listchildren on ftpfolder class

Comment: @holmesfansL Please update your question with more code then.